# How to approximate a Mixture distribution by a single distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Suppose there is a mixture of two Gaussian distributions $G = \alpha N_1 + (1-\alpha)N_2$, where $N_1,N_2$ are known Gaussian distributions, $\alpha$ is the ratio rate. I have two questions:

- How to find a gaussian distribution $N_{approx}$ which can minimum $KL-divergence(N_{approx}||G)$
- Can I get a new gaussian distribution $N_{new}$ from $N_1,N2$, that $N_{new}$ has a smaller standard deviation than $N_1,N_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: If they are independent we can say that $G = N(\alpha \mu_1 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2, \alpha^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-\alpha)^2 \sigma_2^2)$

Comment: Supposing they are dependent, you can get a smaller standard deviation for $N_{new}$ so long as the covariance of the pair $N_1$, $N_2$ is sufficiently negative.